# Neon - load one element from array using vld1q_s32

Tags: arm, neon

I wanna load just one element from array using vld1q_s32, using Neon.

To be specific, if arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4], I want to load each element to int32x4_t A0,
not in same order.

I wanna make A0 to [1, 1, 3, 3].
So I used

```
int32x4_t A0;
A0 = vld1q_s32(arr1[0]);
A0+1 = vld1q_s32(arr1[0]);
A0+2 = vld1q_s32(arr1[2]);
A0+3 = vld1q_s32(arr1[2]);
```

But it did not work.
How can I fix it?
Not using vld1q_s32 is O.K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just load the data as-is then transpose the vector with itself:

```c
A0 = vld1q_s32(arr1);
A0 = vtrn1q_s32(A0, A0);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you more? Is there any more basic solutions? Like if A0 is [4, 1, 2, 2]... like random . Is there any way to load just one element from array to  A0 one by one?

Comment: I suppose you could use [`vsetq_lane_s32`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics?search=vsetq_lane_s32), but it would probably be quite slow; you may as well just reorder the data before loading it since it's not really SIMD at that point anyways. You may want to take a look at [`__builtin_shufflevector`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#langext-builtin-shufflevector) and [`__builtin_shuffle`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions) instead, which make shuffling data pretty straightforward.